# Measure time between steps in Chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to measure the time between steps (F10) when debugging javascript in chrome developer tools?
I know that we can use the console.time(label) and console.timeEnd(label) but the script is very long and I need to find the bottlenecks and using the console.time method would take a long time.

I don't know very well firebug but if it does what I need I'll have no problem in using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Chrome's [Timeline View](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?hl=en)? It tells you how long each function call took to execute.

If you download Chrome Canary and make a Timeline recording it will also show you [per-line information](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/99-line-level-profiling/). (I just played with it and there seems to be some threshold before it starts showing a measurement for a line, but it's worth a try.)

Some docs to get you started:

- [How to use the Timeline tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?hl=en)
- [Analyze runtime performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime?hl=en)
- [Speed up JavaScript execution](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en)